# How to make Qr code size fixed in ZPL regardless of the content?

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I have a problem. I need to print stickers containing QR-codes with my Zebra printer. I'm new to ZPL and when I create a QR code on my sticker it starts growing when it contains more data. It grows so much that it doesn't fit on the sticker anymore. How can I make the size of QR-code fixed so that is doesn't grow anymore? (The data is variable so sometimes its less and sometimes it's more)

I hope someone can help me :)

On `[labelary.com](http://labelary.com/viewer.html)`, i've tried the following;

```
^XA
^LH160,120

^FX QR code serial number
^FO00,00
^BQN,2,10,Q,7
^FH^FDQA,sadfasfsdfdsfsdfdsdfgsdfgdfgdsfsdgsdrdgrdsgdrgdrgrsgsrdgdsgdsrgsdrggdsfgsfgdsfgdfsgssdrgsdrgsdgdgdgsrgsdgdsgdsgrdsgdgrsdgrdgdrsgsrdgsrdgsdrgrdsgdsggsrdgdrsgdsrgdgdgdsgrgdsrgdsrgdrgdsrgrdgsdgsfdasdfdsfdsfdssdffsadfasfd^FS

^XZ
```

There was a similar question asked before but that didn't provide an answer, that was also a long time ago so maybe in the meantime there is a solution for this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used:

```
^BQN,2,10,Q,7
```

You used 10 (maximum) as the magnification factor. You can try reducing 10 to something lower.

```
Accepted Values: 1 to 10

Default Value:
1 on 150 dpi printers
2 on 200 dpi printers
3 on 300 dpi printers
6 on 600 dpi printers
```

You used Q for error correction, you can change Q to L.

```
Accepted Values:
H = ultra-high reliability level
Q = high reliability level
M = standard level
L = high density level

Default Value:
Q = if empty
M = invalid values
```